# Chrome Extension: Open an URL on click?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently trying to make sense of **Google Chrome Extension** development, but I'm having issues understanding it correctly.

I'm developing an extension that hosts a list of URLs and opens them on click. This sounds like a trivial task, but it doesn't work. Probably I'm doing something blatantly wrong.

**Screenshot**

It's not styled, but that's step 2. Basically, I want to open a shortcut on click:

[image: Screenshot]

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Shortcuts",
    "description": "This extension provides shortcuts to locations in Google Chrome",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts":
    [
        {
            "js": [ "popup.js" ],
            "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions":
    [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*"
    ]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chrome Shortcuts</title>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:OpenShortcut('chrome://settings/passwords')">Settings - Passwords</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function OpenShortcut(location)
{
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: location });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot open `chrome://` URLs using standard methods. This is a privileged page and the navigation will fail.

Instead, you need to use `tabs` API. Specifically,

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "chrome://settings/passwords"});
```

Add `active: false` if you need it to open in background without closing the popup.

---

I completely missed the fact you're doing it already, sorry! The issue is with trying to activate your code with `href="javascript:[some code]"`.

This, as well as `onclick="[some code]"`, will fail in a Chrome extension due to the Content Security Policy. Specifically, [inline code is not allowed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) (and you cannot modify the CSP in a way that allows it).

The docs give a solution to this - assign the handler from your code, i.e.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById('link1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    OpenShortcut('chrome://settings/passwords');
  });
});
```

For this to work, add an `id` attribute to your links. `DOMContentLoaded` wrapper is required, since your `popup.js` is executed before your node exists in the DOM.

Comment: You mean like `<a href="#" onclick="chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'chrome://settings/passwords' });">Settings - Passwords</a>`? That also gives me no response on click.

Comment: First, you need to learn to debug it. Right-click the button and select "Inspect popup". This way you get more information than "no response". Second, [read this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution).

Comment: Awesome! I finally got it. Thank you!

Comment: I think primarily the question is about the inline javascript restriction thus maybe better to put it in the answer directly